# VB .Net GeckoFx openload or ok.ru embeds doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, gecko, geckofx

[THIS EXAMPLE IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW7xZ.png)

VB.Net Project;
Doesn't work clicks, and doesn't work play button on iframe.

Web Resource:

```html
<iframe id="x" width="708" height="450" src="//ok.ru/videoembed/96229591732" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'm use SkyBound GeckoFx v1.9.1.0

Comment: you could try a newer geckofx https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geckofx45/

Comment: @Tom how is update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

UPDATE LASTEST VERSION

Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package GeckoFX
```